# I want to change certain names in my UL using a button

Tags: javascript

I want to change 9 of the names in the UL to a red font using a on click button, while the other 3 names remain in a black font. And I want a button to reset the red fonts back to their original font. Can anyone help?

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn2");

for (var btnIndex = 0; btnIndex < buttons.length; btnIndex++) {
  buttons[btnIndex].onclick = function() {
    title.style.color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
  }
} else {
  title1.style.color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="title">John</li>
  <li id="title">Jack</li>
  <li id="title">Joe</li>
  <li id="title1">Jim</li>
  <li id="title">David</li>
  <li id="title">Sam</li>
  <li id="title1">Jay</li>
  <li id="title">Frank</li>
  <li id="title">Tim</li>
  <li id="title">Zack</li>
  <li id="title">Lewis</li>
  <li id="title1">Danny</li>

  <button class="btn" data-color="red">Change 9 names to red</button>
  <button class="btn2" data-color="black">Reset</button>
</ul>
```

Comment: Google for "how to change font color with js" for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your markup, which I'll address below, but to answer your actual question, you can do something like this:

```js
// get references to the buttons
const button1 = document.querySelector('.btn');
const button2 = document.querySelector('.btn2');

// declare a function that adds the class 'red' to items matching the given selector
const select = selector => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].forEach(
    element => element.classList.add('red')
  );
}

// declare a function that removes the given class from all elements that currently have it
const deselect = className => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.' + className)].forEach(
    element => element.classList.remove(className)
  );
}

// add a click handler to the button that invokes the
// select function above for items whose class includes 'title'
button1.addEventListener('click', () => select('.title'));

// add a click handler to the second button that removes the 'red' class from all items
button2.addEventListener('click', () => deselect('red'));
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">John</li>
  <li class="title">Jack</li>
  <li class="title">Joe</li>
  <li class="title1">Jim</li>
  <li class="title">David</li>
  <li class="title">Sam</li>
  <li class="title1">Jay</li>
  <li class="title">Frank</li>
  <li class="title">Tim</li>
  <li class="title">Zack</li>
  <li class="title">Lewis</li>
  <li class="title1">Danny</li>
</ul>

<button class="btn" data-color="red">Change 9 names to red</button>
<button class="btn2" data-color="black">Reset</button>
```

---

### a more efficient solution

This may not suit your needs, but if you just want to change the color of `title` items you could toggle a class on the `<ul>` and apply a css rule:

```js
// get references to the button and ul
const button = document.querySelector('.btn');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

// toggle a class on the ul
button.addEventListener('click', () => ul.classList.toggle('red'));
```

```css
/*
color 'title' items when the
ul has the 'red' class
*/
ul.red .title {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">John</li>
  <li class="title">Jack</li>
  <li class="title">Joe</li>
  <li class="title1">Jim</li>
  <li class="title">David</li>
  <li class="title">Sam</li>
  <li class="title1">Jay</li>
  <li class="title">Frank</li>
  <li class="title">Tim</li>
  <li class="title">Zack</li>
  <li class="title">Lewis</li>
  <li class="title1">Danny</li>
</ul>

<button class="btn">Toggle 'title' items to red</button>
```

### markup issues

1. `id` attributes must be unique within a document. if you need to attach the same identifier to multiple elements use `class` instead.
2. `<button>` cannot be a child of `<ul>`.

Comment: you answered first.. so I guess you should get the points

Comment: @TheBombSquad All helpful answers can and should be up voted.

Answer (score 0):

- First, `id` values must be unique, so you should be using `class` to
  organize the similar `<li>` elements and use `id` to uniquely
  identify the two buttons.
- Also, the only elements that can be a child of a `<ul>`  are `<li>`,
  `<script>` and `<template>` elements, not `<button>`, so the buttons
  have to be moved out of the `ul`.

From there, it's just a matter of setting the two buttons `click` handlers to the same event handler that loops over the `li` elements with the given class (not the buttons as you are trying to do) and adds or removes a pre-made class to the list depending on which button was clicked.

```js
// test.js contents
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", changeColor);

let items = document.querySelectorAll(".title");

function changeColor(event){
  items.forEach(function(item){
    // Figure out which button got us here
    if(event.target.id === "btn"){
      item.classList.add("red");  // Add red
    } else {
      item.classList.remove("red");  // Remove red
    } 
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Change the Certain Font Color with JavaScript</title>
  <style>
    .red {color:red;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="title">John</li>
    <li class="title">Jack</li>
    <li class="title">Joe</li>
    <li class="title1">Jim</li>
    <li class="title">David</li>
    <li class="title">Sam</li>
    <li class="title1">Jay</li>
    <li class="title">Frank</li>
    <li class="title">Tim</li>
    <li class="title">Zack</li>
    <li class="title">Lewis</li>
    <li class="title1">Danny</li>
  </ul>
  
  <button id="btn">Change 9 names to red</button>
  <button id="btn2">Reset</button>

  <script src="test.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Additional notes:**

- You'll want to [stay away from using `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474).
- Rather than looping with counter indexes, it's much simpler to use
  the [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method on the collection returned from [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  You should avoid using inline styles whenever possible as they are the hardest to override and to maintain. Instead, add, remove, or toggle the use of CSS classes with the [`.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which is much simpler to use.